# Data structure in C/C++ for multiple variable size arrays

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

This is the problem at hand:
I have several 10000s of arrays. Each array could be anywhere between 2-15 units in length.
The total length of all the elements in all the arrays and the number of arrays can be computed using some very low cost calculations. But the exact number in each array is not known until some fairly expensive computation is completed.

Since I know the total length of all the elements in all the arrays, I would like to just allocate data for it using just one new/malloc and just set pointers within this allocation. In my current implementation I use memmove to move the data after a certain item is inserted and updates all pointers accordingly.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,

- Sid

Comment: So you're going to be inserting and removing into each individual array?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Your title is ambigious, and the answer for each language will probably be different (C++ will most likely suggest `std` components)

Comment: *better* is a relative term. What are your criteria? Lowering memory usage? Improving access speed?

Comment: How about a vector of vector*? Something like: vector<shared_ptr<vector<Item> > >

Comment: @cppinitiator: vectors of vectors are generally a terrible structure to use as a 2d array.

Comment: @EdS.: Sure, for a fixed-shape 2D array, but for a jagged array—something the OP describes as a bunch of arrays of different lengths—that's a different story.

Comment: @abarnert: Yeah, it's tougher with a jagged array.  However, you could still keep track of the size of each one and use that later as he says he knows the total size up front.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, you can. Even if his row sizes were mutable (which it sounds like they aren't), you could still avoid a vector of vectors with, e.g., a vector plus a freelist plus a vector of offsets. That doesn't necessarily mean you should. For anything more complex than a rectangular array, there are tradeoffs, and sometimes a vector of vector is the best choice, so calling it a terrible structure is misleading.

Comment: @abarnert: It depends on the use case, but for most of them it is in fact terrible.  When iteration comes with a large performance penalty it makes for a poor choice in many (many) circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by better way. If you are looking for something that works faster and can afford some extra memory then you can keep two arrays, one with data, and the other one with the index of the array it belongs. After you added all the data, you can sort by the index and you have all your data split by arrays, finally you sweep the arrays and get the pointer to where each array belongs.

Regarding memory consumption, depending on how many arrays you have, and how big is your data, you can squeeze the index data to the last bits of your data, if you have it bounded by some number. This way, you only need to sort the numbers, and when you are sweeping retrieving the pointer where each array begins, you can clean the top bits.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I know the total length of all the elements in all the arrays, I would like to just allocate data for it using just one new/malloc and just set pointers within this allocation.

You can use one large vector.  You'll need to manually calculate the offset of each sub-array yourself.

vectors guarantee that their data is stored in contiguous memory, but be careful of maintaining references or pointers to individual elements if the vector is used in such a way that may make it reallocate.  Shouldn't be a problem since you're not adding anything beyond the initial size.

```
int main() {    
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.reserve(calc_total_size());
    // now you'll need to manually translate the offset of
    // a given "array" and then add the offset of the element to that 

    T someElem = vec[array_offset + element_offset];
}
```

Comment: You write, "*you're not adding anything beyond the initial size*", but OP wrote, "*I use memmove to move the data after a certain item is inserted and updates all pointers*". I think he is adding items beyond the initial size.

Comment: @Robᵩ: In his current implementation, yes, but he goes on to say that - *"Since I know the total length of all the elements in all the arrays, I would like to just allocate data for it using just one new/malloc and just set pointers within this allocation."*

Comment: Oh, you read it as if he has a **current** and a **proposed** implementation. I read it as if he has just one implementation (which calls `malloc` once & uses `memmove` to insert data). If your inference is correct, then everything I've said is wrong.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Ahh, ok, I see where you're coming from now.  That's what I took his request to mean, perhaps I'm wrong.  I suppose he'll just have to chime in.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, but it looks like there is no set way of doing this. I will have to weigh in the different factors and choose the best method for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Item>> array;
array.resize(cheap_calc());
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
  array[i].resize(expensive_calc(i));
  for(int j = 0; j < array[i].size(); j++) {
    array[i][j] = Item(some_other_calc());
  }
}
```

No pointers, no muss, no fuss.

Comment: I'm -1 because this isn't at all efficient. He wants one allocation, not 100000.

Comment: I don't know what you mean but "at all efficient." Regardless, OP's question is ambiguous. He says he wants one allocation, but then asks if there is a better way. Q: "Is there a better way to do this?" A: "Yes, there is a better way to do this."

Comment: A vector of vectors is a horrible proposition.  One big vector with manual offsets into it would be much better as a 2d array. Locality of data goes out the window (as they're all allocating separate private stores) and causes a ton of unnecessary allocations.  I'm with @Pubby.

Comment: @EdS.: right, one big vector with a separate "remapping" layer, allowing you to map "array A, index 542" into "index 457281" would be my solution. Athough it's hard to know what the OP means by "better" in this context. Better (i.e. higher) performance? Better (i.e. more) usability? Better (i.e. lower) memory footprint?

Comment: A problem with one big vector is insert is now an O(∑(n)) instead of O(n), where `n` is average 1D vector length. I claim that time cost due to algorithmic complexity is likely to swamp time cost due to memory cache effects.

Comment: @Robᵩ: The OP didn't say that he needed to perform any insertions.  He went as far to say that he simply needs a big chunk of memory and that he knows the total size up front.  I also don't think you can claim that without having a clue as to how this vector will be used.  If most of his program's time is spent iterating over it then cache misses will be a relatively *huge* cost.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for memory efficiency, speed efficiency, or simplicity?

You can always write or download a dead-simple pool allocator, then pass that as the allocator to the appropriate data structures. Because you know the total size in advance, and never need to resize vectors or add new ones, this can be even simpler than a typical pool allocator. Just `malloc` all of the storage in one big block, and keep a single pointer to the next block. To allocate n bytes, `T *ret = nextBlock; nextBlock += n; return ret;`. If your objects are trivial and don't need destruction, you can even just do one big `free` at the end.

This means you can use any data structure you want, or compare and contrast different ones. A `vector` of `vector`s? A giant `vector` of cells plus a `vector` of offsets? Something else you came up with that sounds crazy but just might work? You can compare their readability, usability, and performance without worrying about the memory allocation side of things.

(Of course if your goal is speed, packing things this way may not be the best answer. You can often gain a lot of speed by wasting a little space to improve your cache and/or page alignment. You *could* write a fancy allocator that, e.g., allocates vector space in a transposed way to improve the performance of your algorithm that does column-major where it should do row-major and vice-versa, but at that point, it's probably easier to tweak your algorithms than your allocator.)